# Populating a config file when a pod starts

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run a legacy application inside Kubernetes. The application consists of one of more controllers, and one or more workers. The workers and controllers can be scaled independently. The controllers take a configuration file as a command line option, and the configuration looks similar to the following:

```
instanceId=hostname_of_machine
Memory=XXX
....
```

I need to be able to populate the instanceId field with the name of the machine, and this needs to be stable over time. What are the general guidelines for implementing something like this? The application doesn't support environment variables, so my first thought was to record the stateful set stable network ID in an environment variable and rewrite the configuration file with an init container. Is there a cleaner way to approach this? I haven't found a whole lot of solutions when I searched the 'net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's the way to do it (use an initContainer to update the config file).

Comment: Are there advantages to using initContainers over something like an entrypoint? I'm assuming the init container would need a shared volume of some type.

Comment: An initContainer only runs when the pod starts (and yes, you use a shared emptyDir volume), an entry point runs on every container start and requires modifying the container. Another option is a sidecar with a shared volume if you want to continually update the config, if the app supports that but most dont.